# python datetime.date minimal year possible

Tags: python, date, datetime

It seems that minimal year possible for python's date is 1. What if I want 0 or -1 or less e.g. if I write a program about dinosaurs. What should I do?
P.S. tbh, I don't care about dinosaurs, I only want year 0, is there any workaround?

Comment: No, there is not. Note that the `datetime` module implements a Gregorian calendar (first introduced 1582) and does not take into account calendar rearrangements throughout history either, so you cannot track dates accurately over centuries time *anyway*. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MartijnPieters honestly I tried to bypass some validation, and solved my problem another way, so I was just also curious about year 0. Your comment can be answer to this question tho, thank you!

Comment: @DanielRoseman thats right, there was no 0 year in Gregorian calendar, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

Note that the datetime module implements the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (first introduced 1582) which does not *have* a year 0. It does not take into account calendar rearrangements throughout history either, so you cannot track dates accurately over centuries time anyway.